# Requesting Microsoft Graph /me/joinedTeams returns 404

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, http-status-code-404, microsoft-teams

I signed into [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), tried to test several GET calls but many fail. For example a simple GET call for `me/joinedTeams` always fails with error 404. The account that is signed into the Graph explorer is an admin on Azure portal and also the same account that created the Teams instance and a few teams channels. I even invited another account to the Teams channel, logged into the Graph Explorer with that account and get the same 404 error.

When looking at the permissions tab, all permissions show a check except for `Team.ReadBasic.All` which has a cross. Clicking on "Consent" button does bring up an empty dialog for a split second, but then goes away and the cross remains.

Comment: We are not able to repro the issue at our end. To get the list joined teams you need permissions as listed Team.ReadBasic.All, TeamSettings.Read.All, TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All, User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All - Could you please check  did you added all the required permissions? Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for more info ?

Comment: @Stride 9- Are you still stuck on this?

Comment: yes, I am still stuck. The account is a work account, it is a member of the Azure AD, and it has Global Administrator permissions. Yet a GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams always results in an error 404.

Comment: perhaps naive question - should this work with an Azure AD for Office 365 license, or will we need to upgrade to Azure AD Premium P1 or P2?

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that the following 3 conditions are met:

- Enter the correct api: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams`.
- Your account type cannot be a personal Microsoft account, it should be a work or school account.
- Your account cannot be a guest account of Azure AD, it must be a **member** account of Azure AD, and it should have the role of a `global administrator`.

Comment: yes. I used exactly that API, the account if a work account, is a member of the Azure AD, and it has Global Administrator permissions. Yet a GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams always results in an error 404.